# Bridge-Pattern or Entity-Component-System

Tags: c#, design-patterns, comparative-review, entity-component-system

I want to learn how/when/why to use the *GoF Design Patterns*.  These last days are dedicated to the *Bridge Pattern*, which means:

> Decouple an abstraction from its implementation so that the two can vary independently.

Everyone has a different understanding of this vague description, but if I well-understood the global point, it cuts an abstraction into multiple independant implementations which relies on each other, in a chain.

---

On this premise, let's try to implement a *four-arrow remote control*. First, let's define what's awaited with interfaces:

```
public interface ITopBottomButtonsControl
{
    void TopButtonPressed();
    void BottomButtonPressed();
}

public interface ILeftRightButtonsControl
{
    void LeftButtonPressed();
    void RightButtonPressed();
}

public interface IRemoteControl : 
    ILeftRightButtonsControl, 
    ITopBottomButtonsControl
{ }
```

---

Here is an example of the BP implementation:

```
public class ChannelControl : ILeftRightButtonsControl
{
    public void LeftButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Previous channel");
    public void RightButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Next channel");
}

public class ChapterControl : ILeftRightButtonsControl
{
    public void LeftButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Previous chapter");
    public void RightButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Next chapter");
}
```

---

```
public abstract class BPRemoteControl : IRemoteControl
{
    ILeftRightButtonsControl LeftRightControl { get; }

    public BPRemoteControl(ILeftRightButtonsControl leftRight)
    {
        LeftRightControl = leftRight;
    }

    public void LeftButtonPressed() => LeftRightControl.LeftButtonPressed();
    public void RightButtonPressed() => LeftRightControl.RightButtonPressed();

    public abstract void TopButtonPressed();
    public abstract void BottomButtonPressed();
}
```

---

```
public class SpeedControl : BPRemoteControl
{
    public SpeedControl(ILeftRightButtonsControl leftRight) : base(leftRight) { }

    public override void BottomButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Slow down");
    public override void TopButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Speed up");
}

public class VolumeControl : BPRemoteControl
{
    public VolumeControl(ILeftRightButtonsControl leftRight) : base(leftRight) { }

    public override void BottomButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Volume down");
    public override void TopButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Volume up");
}
```

---

The fact is that, when I implemented this to test the pattern, it made me think back the *Entity Component System*. So, I tried to implement the same application, but this time with an ECS approach.
The classes `ChannelControl` and `ChapterControl` remains the same, but the rest is different:

```
public class SpeedControl : ITopBottomButtonsControl
{
    public void BottomButtonPressed() => Console.Write("Slow down");
    public void TopButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Speed up");
}

public class VolumeControl : ITopBottomButtonsControl
{
    public void BottomButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Volume down");
    public void TopButtonPressed() => Console.WriteLine("Volume up");
}
```

---

```
public class ECSRemoteController : IRemoteControl
{
    private ITopBottomButtonsControl TopBottomButtonsComponent { get; }
    private ILeftRightButtonsControl LeftRightButtonsComponent { get; }

    public ECSRemoteController(ITopBottomButtonsControl topBottom, ILeftRightButtonsControl leftRight)
    {
        TopBottomButtonsComponent = topBottom;
        LeftRightButtonsComponent = leftRight;
    }

    public void TopButtonPressed() => TopBottomButtonsComponent.TopButtonPressed();
    public void BottomButtonPressed() => TopBottomButtonsComponent.BottomButtonPressed();

    public void LeftButtonPressed() => LeftRightButtonsComponent.LeftButtonPressed();
    public void RightButtonPressed() => LeftRightButtonsComponent.RightButtonPressed();
}
```

---

Finally, these two solutions seems to be the same, with the following difference:

> The Bridge Pattern is vertically-organized: `S(a -> b -> c)`
>   The Entity-Component-System is horizontally-organized: `S(a, b, c)`

Is there really a difference between these two solutions? When should one be prefered to the other?

---

**HOW TO TEST:** separate the two solutions into two folders `BridgePattern` and `EntityComponentPattern`, and fill the console application with the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BridgePattern();
        Console.WriteLine();
        EntityComponentSystem();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void BridgePattern()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine("BridgePattern version");
        Console.WriteLine("----------");

        IRemoteControl TVRemoteControl = new BridgePattern.VolumeControl(new BridgePattern.ChannelControl());
        IRemoteControl DVDRemoteControl = new BridgePattern.SpeedControl(new BridgePattern.ChapterControl());

        Console.WriteLine($"1. {nameof(TVRemoteControl)}:");
        UseRemoteControl(TVRemoteControl);

        Console.WriteLine($"2. {nameof(DVDRemoteControl)}:");
        UseRemoteControl(DVDRemoteControl);
    }

    static void EntityComponentSystem()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("EntityComponentSystem version");
        Console.WriteLine("----------");

        IRemoteControl TVRemoteControl = new EntityComponentSystem.ECSRemoteController(new EntityComponentSystem.VolumeControl(), new EntityComponentSystem.ChannelControl());
        IRemoteControl DVDRemoteControl = new EntityComponentSystem.ECSRemoteController(new EntityComponentSystem.SpeedControl(), new EntityComponentSystem.ChapterControl());

        Console.WriteLine($"1. {nameof(TVRemoteControl)}:");
        UseRemoteControl(TVRemoteControl);

        Console.WriteLine($"2. {nameof(DVDRemoteControl)}:");
        UseRemoteControl(DVDRemoteControl);
    }

    static void UseRemoteControl(IRemoteControl remoteControl)
    {
        remoteControl.LeftButtonPressed();
        remoteControl.RightButtonPressed();
        remoteControl.TopButtonPressed();
        remoteControl.BottomButtonPressed();
    }
```

Comment: I find it's very cool that you've created this code with volume and remote controls rather than with meaningless foos and bars ;-)

Comment: I for some reason cannot post an answer (CR throws errors and CAPTCHA on me), so, short answer is: those two sub-interfaces appear to be independent (you don't need the other for implementation), therefore I would use ECS. BP is suitable e.g. for IList extending ICollection (IList without Count from ICollection would be nonsense and you need access to internal data - array of elements and size).

Comment: So, BP is when a step rely on an other one, and ECS is when interfaces are autonomous? PS: if you want, I can create an answer for you, you'll edit it and I'll accept

Comment: @MaximeRecuerda: Let us wait for somebody with better understanding of the theory. I am more practical than theoretical guy, so, your ECS example appears more appropriate to me, because the two interfaces are independent. I am not so sure how BP is actually specified and used, IList/ICollection was just a counter example where the other approach would be appropriate (because you simply cannot use ECS for it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hybrid Pattern

The *bridge pattern* you have implemented is a combination of the *composite pattern* and *inheritance*. Why did you decide to let your `ILeftRightButtonsControl` implementation use composition and `ITopBottomButtonsControl` use inheritance?

> ```
> public abstract class BPRemoteControl : IRemoteControl
> {
>     ILeftRightButtonsControl LeftRightControl { get; }
>
>     public BPRemoteControl(ILeftRightButtonsControl leftRight)
>     {
>         LeftRightControl = leftRight;
>     }
>
>     public void LeftButtonPressed() => LeftRightControl.LeftButtonPressed();
>     public void RightButtonPressed() => LeftRightControl.RightButtonPressed();
>
>     public abstract void TopButtonPressed();
>     public abstract void BottomButtonPressed();
> }
> ```

---

### Bridge Pattern

A useful implementation of the *bridge pattern* would be if `ChannelControl`, `ChapterControl` were third-party classes from let's say `OtherDomain` that do not adhere to your interfaces. If these other classes would have other interfaces, you might also consider the *adapter pattern* instead.

You would then create a bridge for `OtherDomain.ChannelControl`.

```
public class ChannelControlBridge : ILeftRightButtonsControl
{
    private OtherDomain.ChannelControl impl;
    public ChannelControlBridge (OtherDomain.ChannelControl impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }
    // the name of the operations happens to be the same in their domain
    // but this is not a requirement
    public void LeftButtonPressed() => impl.LeftButtonPressed();
    public void RightButtonPressed() => impl.RightButtonPressed();
}
```

And a bridge for `OtherDomain.ChapterControl`.

```
public class ChapterControlBridge : ILeftRightButtonsControl
{
    private OtherDomain.ChapterControl impl;
    public ChapterControlBridge (OtherDomain.ChapterControl impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }
    // the name of the operations happens to be the same in their domain
    // but this is not a requirement
    public void LeftButtonPressed() => impl.LeftButtonPressed();
    public void RightButtonPressed() => impl.RightButtonPressed();
}
```

---

### Adapter Pattern

The *adapter pattern* could be implemented if `ChannelControl`, `ChapterControl` were third-party classes from let's say `OtherDomain` that do not adhere to your interfaces, but use their own interfaces instead.

You would then create and adapter for `OtherDomain.IChannelControl`.

```
public class ChannelControlAdapter : ILeftRightButtonsControl
{
    private OtherDomain.IChannelControl impl;
    public ChannelControlAdapter (OtherDomain.IChannelControl impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }
    // the name of the operations happens to be the same in their domain
    // but this is not a requirement
    public void LeftButtonPressed() => impl.LeftButtonPressed();
    public void RightButtonPressed() => impl.RightButtonPressed();
}
```

And an adapter for `OtherDomain.IChapterControl`.

```
public class ChapterControlAdapter : ILeftRightButtonsControl
{
    private OtherDomain.IChapterControl impl;
    public ChapterControlAdapter (OtherDomain.IChapterControl impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }
    // the name of the operations happens to be the same in their domain
    // but this is not a requirement
    public void LeftButtonPressed() => impl.LeftButtonPressed();
    public void RightButtonPressed() => impl.RightButtonPressed();
}
```

---

### Composite Pattern

Your ECS is a perfect example of the *composite pattern* by forwarding the operations to your inner components.

> ```
> public class ECSRemoteController : IRemoteControl
> {
>     private ITopBottomButtonsControl TopBottomButtonsComponent { get; }
>     private ILeftRightButtonsControl LeftRightButtonsComponent { get; }
>
>     public ECSRemoteController(ITopBottomButtonsControl topBottom, 
>         ILeftRightButtonsControl leftRight)
>     {
>         TopBottomButtonsComponent = topBottom;
>         LeftRightButtonsComponent = leftRight;
>     }
>
>     public void TopButtonPressed() => TopBottomButtonsComponent.TopButtonPressed();
>     public void BottomButtonPressed() => TopBottomButtonsComponent.BottomButtonPressed();
>
>     public void LeftButtonPressed() => LeftRightButtonsComponent.LeftButtonPressed();
>     public void RightButtonPressed() => LeftRightButtonsComponent.RightButtonPressed();
> }
> ```

Comment: This is the kind of answer that everyone would receive. Clear, examples, explanation, thank you so much.